# How Use on_command_error() to detect AttributeError

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

I am trying to detect when someone uses a command outside the server. I want to just have one on_command_error() function so I am trying to detect the Attribute Error: 'NoneType' has no attribute 'id'. However, I do not now what to put, I tried AttributeError, but it wouldn't detect it.

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, AttributeError):
    await ctx.send('You Cannot Use This Command Outside Of The Server')
  else:
    print(error)
```

Does anyone know what to use for the argument AttributeError is taking right now?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you aware that there is no closing quotation mark?

Comment: That was only here, I had it correctly in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really handle errors like that in the error handler, nonetheless you can do it with the following:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    # If an error happens inside the command,
    # discord.py wraps it around with `commands.CommandInvokeError` 
    # which has the `original` attribute which is the "original" error
    error = getattr(error, "original", error)
    if isinstance(error, AttributeError):
        ...
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py actually has a check built in for guild-only commands. [`commands.guild_only()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.guild_only).

So, right below (or before) the check for defining a discord command (`@bot.command()`), add the decorator `@commands.guild_only`.

If this command is run outside of a server, it will raise a [NoPrivateMessage](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.NoPrivateMessage) exception. You can use the error handler to catch this and send a message accordingly.